# How to change date format in Calendar Widget of SmartGWT?

Tags: smartgwt

Default calendar widget of Smartgwt Component shows date as Sun 10/31 ( MM/DD format ) .

http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#simple_calendar_category

How can I change the date format to DD/MM formatin Calendar Widget ?

Thanks in advance for having a look, 
Sachin

Answer (score 2):

SmartGwt provides a static DateUtil for changing date formats.Put the following code somewhere in your application and it will change the date format through out the application

```
DateUtil.setShortDateDisplayFormatter(new DateDisplayFormatter() {
     public String format(Date date) {
         if(date == null) return null;
         final DateTimeFormat dateFormatter = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("DD/MM/yyyy");
         String format = dateFormatter.format(date);
         return format;
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to the `com.smartgwt.client.util.DateUtil` specifically to the methods `setShortDateDisplayFormat` and `setShortDateDisplayFormatter`

This should solve your problem, according to the documentation.

Comment: Hi Carlos, I have added following in my code  com.smartgwt.client.util.DateUtil.setShortDateDisplayFormat(DateDisplayFormat.TOEUROPEANSHORTDATE);  before calendar widget Calendar calendar = new Calendar();. But this doesnt work. Am I missing anything ? I would appreciate if you can paste the code.

Comment: @Sachin, I'm not using SmartGWT due to this kind of problems, I simply checked the documentation and the forums looking for a solution.
If you can live without SmarGWT, try gwt-cal

Answer (score 0):

put

```
this.setDateFormatter(DateDisplayFormat.TOEUROPEANSHORTDATE);
```

in constructor

Answer (score 0):

[@aruns](https://stackoverflow.com/users/511889/aruns) is correct, however another step is need if you are using [RelativeDateItem](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwtee/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/fields/RelativeDateItem.html)

```
      DateUtil.setShortDatetimeDisplayFormatter(new DateDisplayFormatter()
      {
         public String format(Date date)
         {
            if(date == null)
            {
               return null;
            }
            else
            {
               final DateTimeFormat dateFormatter = DateTimeFormat.getFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
               return dateFormatter.format(date);
            }

         }
      });

      DateUtil.setDateParser(new DateParser()
      {
         public Date parse(String dateString)
         {
            final DateTimeFormat format = DateTimeFormat.getFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
            return format.parse(dateString);
         }
      });
```

The [DateFormat](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/DateTimeFormat.html) is defined in the GWT documentation